# Secure the formula behind PHPExcel

Tags: php, security, phpexcel

Hello everyone :D How do I secure the formula (in the Excel doc) behind PHPExcel?

I am using a HTML form to POST a user-inputed value, have the PHP retrive the formula from the Excel doc and calculate with that user-inputed value, then return the answer of the calculation to the user.
The formula isn't in the HTML or PHP script, it is all inside the Excel doc.

How do I protect the formula in the Excel doc? I have set the file permission of the Excel docs in the ftp to 400 (no read, write, excute permission for Group and Public, Owner has only read permission), so the public cannot download them.
But is this protection sufficient? Are there other methods to read the formula inside these Excel docs?

For those wondering, the formula inside this Excel Docs is `=IF(A1>0,"Greater than Zero",IF(A1<0,"Less than Zero","Equals Zero"))` This formula is what I want to protect, this is what I don't want anyone to see, except, for those with server access of course.

HTML Form Script

```
<form action="./FirstInteraction.php" method="post">
Input A1: <input type="number" name="A1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP Script: FirstInteraction.php

```
/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/** Load Excel File **/
$inputFileName = './TrueFalse.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

/** Change A1 Value **/
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1',$_REQUEST["A1"]);

/** Calculate and State B1 Value **/
echo "<br> It is ".$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getCalculatedValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody can access your .xlsx file, nor download it, and in addition the PHP script is only server-side visible, there's no need of any further secureness.

However, what are your fears about it? How do you think they can access your formula? If you have some suggestions regarding any exploit, maybe we could give a proper suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: I just started learning PHP two days ago, that's why I am so worried, because I am not sure what exploit is and is not possible.

Comment: In a general occasion, if you have made your excel file inaccessible from other source, than the server, you don't need any other protection. Only beware of your user-inputs, i.e. don't make a field that the user fills, to be passed to eval() function, where they can execute a PHP code and not only use code to read your file, but some more harmful actions.

Answer (score 1):

How do you mean protect? If you mean prevent that cell from being edited, then:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getProtection()->setLocked(
    PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
```

Comment: Oh, I meant protecting the information insdie the cell from being read by the public. :D

Comment: If you need to prevent it from being read by the public, you make your workbook inaccessible by storing it outside of the web accessible directories (i.e. outside of the web root or its subdirectories).

Comment: Are there exploits that will allow the public to read the information via other script commands?

Comment: Yes, there's plenty - but a short StackOverflow answer can't teach you all aspects of PHP security